# Simplification of a min-max problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I have an optimisation problem to solve. The book I'm following says that the original problem can be rewritten in a simpler way by observing that one of the unknowns is a subset of the $Y-1$ dimensional simplex. I'm struggling to write down this equivalent way.

---

**Original problem**

Let me first introduce some notation. $B,L,Q$ are $Y\times 1$ vector.  $Q_y\equiv Q(y)$ is the $y$-th element of $Q$. $R$ is a 3d matrix of size $Y\times V \times E$. $R_{y,v,e}\equiv R(Y,V,E)$ is the $(y,v,e)$-th element of $R$. $P$ is an $E\times 1$ vector. $P_e\equiv P(e)$ is the $e$-th element of $P$.

The original problem is:

$$
\text{max}_{B}\text{ min}_{Q,R}\text{ } B^T (L-Q)\\
\text{s.t.} \\
Q_y - \sum_{e=1,..,E,v=1,...,V} R_{y,v,e} \times P_e=0 \text{ }\forall y=1,...,Y\\
R\in [0,1]^{Y\times V\times E}\\
\sum_{y=1,...,Y,v=1,...,V}R_{y,v,e}-1=0 \text{ }\forall e=1,...,E\\
\sum_{y=1,...,Y} R_{y,v,e}-1=0 \text{ }\forall e=1,...,E,v=1,...,V\\
\sum_{v=1,...,V} R_{y,v,e}-1=0 \text{ }\forall e=1,...,E,y=1,...,Y\\
Q\in [0,1]^Y\\
\sum_{y=1,...,Y}Q_y-1=0\\
B^TB\leq 1\\
$$

---

**Transformed problem**

The exercise says: given that $Q$ belongs to the $Y-1$ dimensional simplex, the problem above can be rewritten in a simpler way. Could you check whether my attempt is correct? If not, could you fix it? Are some constraints superfluous?

Let $Z\equiv L-Q$. Let $\tilde{B}$ be the $Y\times 1$ vector collecting the first $Y-1$ elements of $B$ and having as last element a zero.

$$
\text{max}_{\tilde{B}}\text{ min}_{Z,R}\text{ } \tilde{B}^T Z\\
\text{s.t.} \\
(L_y-Z_y) - \sum_{e=1,..,E,v=1,...,V} R_{y,v,e} \times P_e=0 \text{ }\forall y=1,...,Y\\
R\in [0,1]^{Y\times V\times E}\\
\sum_{y=1,...,Y,v=1,...,V}R_{y,v,e}-1=0 \text{ }\forall e=1,...,E\\
\sum_{y=1,...,Y} R_{y,v,e}-1=0 \text{ }\forall e=1,...,E,v=1,...,V\\
\sum_{v=1,...,V} R_{y,v,e}-1=0 \text{ }\forall e=1,...,E,y=1,...,Y\\
L-Z\in [0,1]^Y\\
\sum_{y=1,...,Y}(L_y-Z_y)-1=0\\
\tilde{B}^T\tilde{B}\leq 1\\
$$

Also, what is the technical name of this optimisation problem? It looks to me "a constrained optimisation problem with linear objective function and linear and quadratic constraints". Is there a shorter way to call it?

Comment: Hint: the minimum of a linear function over a polyhedral set occurs at a corner point of that set